# Quick open new file on the current tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like to code using two panes and navigating my code with quick open as much as possible.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9P6J.png)

The problem is that every time I use Quick Open (Ctrl + P on Windows) it opens the file on another tab. I don't like tabs but there's no way to disable them as far as I know. You can only hide the tabs but that's not really useful since other tabs will be open in the background anyway.

Is there a way to make quick open use the current tab? Or disable tabs altogether and not just hide them?

Thanks

Comment: Clearly not a user-centric approach. Why not try using *vim*?

Comment: Actually, after messing around for a while this does seem to be the default behavior except for the first time you split the panes. Don't know if this is intended behavior or a bug but it does work once you close the recently created tab after the split.

Answer (score 0):

To disable tabs, just add:

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": false
```

to your user settings.

Also note that VSCode normally opens files in preview mode. This is indicated by an italicized file name in the workbench. Files in preview mode are not kept open when you quick open another file. You can disable previews by setting:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

Comment: That is incorrect, that option only hides the tabs and not disable them which is pretty much useless if you ask me.

Comment: Yes, with tabs disabled we still keep a stack of open editors for quick switching. There is no option to force there to only be a single file open at a time. That's where previews come into play. Preview editors are reused in this way